# AS3 Error #2044. Once dissmissed the app works fine

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working in as3 and my code is producing an error: "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed."

Other then the fact that the app is producing this error and interrupting users who have a the debug version of the adobe flash player the app works just fine, I "Dismiss All" errors and

I've been debugging the program, stepping through one line at a time, trying to see exactly what it's failing to load and I can figure it out.  From what research I've done it seems like the error is caused by urls being wrong or resources not being present, but as I've said, the app works exactly as expected.

here is a link to the app if you have debugger version of flash you'll see when it happens:
http://www.playmatics.com/parents_connect/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are loading files off a server, I would suggest looking for server errors on file requests as this could be the source of your problem.

However, you might still want to properly handle the event thrown by the player in order to avoid the error from being displayed:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IOError, handleIOErrorEvent);

var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest('srcURL');
loader.load(urlReq);

protected function handleIOErrorEvent(event:IOErrorEvent):void { 
    trace('handleIOErrorEvent: ' + event);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

Not related to your problem... two files appear as not found – 404 errors – on your server:

http://www.playmatics.com/parents_connect/history/history.js
http://www.playmatics.com/parents_connect/history/history.css

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I solved it.  I was loading images somewhere that I didn't have any images to load.  This problem lead me to reorganize some of my code base and everything is making more sense now.  I added some error checking too.  Thanks for the help.